# SSRS Downgrade from 2019 to 2017

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2017, ssrs-2019

We are currently running SQL Server 2017 and I installed SSRS 2019 evaluation by an accident, only realizing after users had been working on it. What would be the best procedure to downgrade from SSRS 2019 to 2017 without affecting the reports already created?

Side question - Can my license for SQL Server 2017 work to license my SSRS 2019?

Comment: License questions are off-topic for [so], however, I can say: no a 2017 license won't work on a 2019 service (the reverse is not true though). If you want to use 2019, you need a 2019 or later licence.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because license questions are not suitable for this site

Comment: That is only part of it; the other is how to downgrade SSRS 2019 to SSRS 2017, @DaleK .

Comment: Though, I'm not sure you *can* downgrade the version; you can downgrade the edition (say from Enterprise to standard) but not version. Likely you'll need to uninstall SSRS 2019 and then install 2017 (or otherwise buy a 2019 licence).

Comment: _... without affecting the reports already created?_ Too late. SSRS 2019 will have upgraded the database schemas to the newer version the first time it ran. Not only will you have to figure out how to uninstall SSRS 2019 so you can reinstall SSRS 2017 but you'll have to restore the ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB databases from the latest (pre-upgrade) backups.

Comment: So I've created a test environment and I just uninstalled SSRS 2019 and reinstalled 2017. Setup the config the same as the live server and tried opening SSRS. I get the error saying Scale-out deployment is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services. Is there any work-around for this?